# onCreateContextMenu in PreferenceFragment is not called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I have a little problem with Android not reacting the way I tell it to do.
Maybe I'm just missing a little thing somewhere and the solution is obvious, but currently I don't see it.

Ok, the scenario:
I'm currently refactoring the code of an Android App that was written by a former employee of my company. This app uses the PreferenceActivity class in order to let the user configure its settings. The functionality is working so far, but Eclipse warns me that several methods of the PreferenceActivity class are deprecated. Google states that instead of the PreferenceActivity class the PreferenceFragment class should be used. Currently I'm trying to modify the app in a way, where the same functionality of the current PreferenceActivity class is handled by a PreferenceFragment and an additional PreferenceActivity just displays the fragment via the fragment manager. This also works for most of the code (as far as I can say by now), but there is one thing that doesn't work anymore with this approach:

The former PreferenceActivity was showing a context menu with additional options on a long-press of some specific preference elements, which was working fine before. But now in the PreferenceFragment the context menu isn't displayd anymore (`onCreateContextMenu(...)` never gets called). I'm using `registerForContextMenu(...)` in my `onCreateView(...)` method to register the ListView of the preference elements for the context menu, which should work according to examples that I found, but in my case it does not so far.

The code is very extensive, so I wont post it here. But the structure is basically the same like in this example: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/06/09/display-context-menu-fragment/
If someone needs futher information, please feel free to ask.

Hopefully someone can help me with this issue. :)

Cheers,
Chris